# Must every right-inverse of a linear transformation be a linear transformation?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let T be a linear transformation $\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$. Let S be the right-inverse of T. Does S have to be linear transformation?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I think that since every matrix is a linear transformation and right inverse of a matrix is a matrix itself, hence it can be thought of as a linear transformation.

Comment: Every matrix is not a linear transformation. A linear transformation needs to have the zero-vector in the range.

Comment: ok but multiply the matrix be the zero vector and you get the zero vector in the range?

Comment: That does not make sense to me.

Comment: Any linear map $T$ can be uniquely represented by a matrix $M$ such that $T(v) =M\cdot v$, once bases are fixed in the domain and codomain, and the zero vector is always in the range (which is the column space of the matrix, using the given basis).

Comment: I don't see how this fits into the conversation.

Comment: @JamesSmith: Berci was expressing more precisely what mathpadawan was trying to get at.

Comment: @JamesSmith All matrices are linear transformations. Just apply the matrix to a sum of vectors: $M(u+v) = Mu + Mv$. As for the zero vector: $0$ is in the range means $0 = Mv$ for some $v$. Well $M0 = 0$, take $v=0$.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 5):

Actually, if the mapping $S:\Bbb R^3\to\Bbb R^2$ satisfies $T(S(v))=v$ for all $v\in\Bbb R^3$, that would imply $T$ is surjective, which is impossible if $T$ is linear, by considering the dimensions.

However, if $T$ is injective, it has left inverses, and it can also have *nonlinear* left inverses, e.g. if $T(a, b) =(a, b, 0)$ and 
$$S(a,b,c):=(a+c^2, b+c^2)$$

Comment: So you say that T does not have a right-inverse? If so, I would disagree.

Comment: $T$ cannot be surjective.

Comment: It has just come to my attention that T should have been $\mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$. I made a typo. I will not edit the question, because your answer is quite good and may help others.

Comment: If $T:\Bbb R^3\to\Bbb R^2$, surjective, e.g. $T(a, b, c) =(a, b)$, then similarly as above, for example $S(a,b)=(a, b, a^2)$ is a nonlinear right inverse of $T$.

Answer (score 2):

**No**

(Actually a linear map $\mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R^3$ cannot have a right inverse, since having a right inverse is equivalent to being surjective, and linear maps have the dimension of the range at most the dimension of the domain, so there are no surjective linear maps $\mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R^3$)

BUT ANYWAY. . . .

Consider the projection map $P: \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R$ given by $P(x,y) = x$. Let $f : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ be your favourite nonlinear function and define the right-inverse $Q: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R^2$ by $Q(x) = (x,f(x))$.

Then we have $P\circ Q(x) = P(Q(x))=P(x,f(x))= x$ so this is indeed a right inverse.

To see $Q$ is nonlinear observe the image is the graph of the function $f$ which is not a linear subspace of $\mathbb R^2$. That means $Q$ is nonlinear.

Answer (score 1):

By definition, if $S$ is a right-inverse of $T,$ then $S:\Bbb R^3\to\Bbb R^2$ has the property that for all $\vec v\in\Bbb R^2,$ we have $(T\circ S)(\vec v)=\vec v.$ However, by Rank-Nullity, there is a vector $\vec u\in\Bbb R^3$ with $\vec u\neq\vec 0_3,$ such that $S(\vec u)=\vec 0_2,$ so that since $T$ is a linear transformation, we would have $\vec u=(T\circ S)(\vec u)=T\bigl(S(\vec u)\bigr)=T(\vec 0_2)=\vec 0_3\neq\vec u.$ Thus, $T$ has no right-inverse.

On the other hand, $T$ will have left-inverses (infinitely-many of them, in fact) so long as its null space contains only $\vec{0}_2,$ and exactly one of the left-inverses (the one sending all elements outside the range of $T$ to $\vec{0}_2$) is a linear transformation.

Comment: It has just come to my attention that T should have been $\mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$. I made a typo. I will not edit the question, because your answer is quite good and may help others.

Answer (score 0):

If $T:X\to Y$ is injective but not surjective, consider a left-inverse $S$, i.e. a map $Y\to X$ such that $$S(T(x)) = x\text{ for all }x\in X.$$ Note that this equation *only* says something about how $S$ acts on the range (image) of $T$. For the points of $Y$ that are outside the range of $T$, we are free to prescribe absolutely *any* behavior for $S$.

Similarly, if $T:X\to Y$ is instead surjective but not injective, we consider a right-inverse $S$, $$T(S(y)) = y\text{ for all }y\in Y.$$ This means that for a $y\in Y$, the map $S$ just picks *one* of the inverse images of $y$ under $T$. Every time we have a $y$ that is "hit" by more than one $x$ under $T$, we have the freedom to choose any of them as our value $S(y)$.

The above is true in general (in the category of arbitrary sets and maps). If we consider the case where $X$ and $Y$ are vector spaces (or more concretely $X=\mathbb{R}^n$ and $Y=\mathbb{R}^m$), and where $T$ is a linear map, it is clear (I think; left to the reader) that our freedom to mingle with $S$ concerns full subspaces (or complements of subspaces) and we can pick a completely "wild" behavior of $S$. In particular, we can ensure that $S$ is not a linear map.